# Proof of chain rule for entropy of random variables

Tags: probability, summation, random-variables, entropy

I have the following proof for the chain rule for entropy of random variables:
We write:

\begin{eqnarray*}
H(X_1,X_2,...,X_n)&=&-\sum\limits_{x_1,x_2,...,x_n}p(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)logp(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)
\\&=&-\sum\limits_{x_1,x_2,...,x_n}p(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)log\prod\limits_{i=1}^{n}p(x_i|x_{i-1},...,x_1)
\\&=&-\sum\limits_{x_1,x_2,...,x_n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n p(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)logp(x_i|x_{i-1},...,x_1)
\\&=&-\sum\limits_{x_1,x_2,...,x_i}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n p(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)logp(x_i|x_{i-1},...,x_1)
\\&=&\sum\limits_{i=1}^n H(X_i|X_{i-1},...,X_1)
\end{eqnarray*}

Basically, I have 2 questions: first how we get from line 1 to line 2. Is it some kind of Markov property? And second, why the summation lower boundary changes in line 4?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first line is just conditioning: 
\begin{align}
&p(x_1,x_2) = p(x_1)p(x_2|x_1)\\
&p(x_1,x_2, x_3) = p(x_1)p(x_2|x_1)p(x_3|x_1,x_2)
\end{align}
and in general: 
$$ p(x_1, ..., x_n) = p(x_1)\prod_{i=2}^np(x_i|x_{i-1}, ..., x_1) = \prod_{i=1}^n p(x_i|x_{i-1}, ...) $$

---

I agree the third-to-fourth line seems unclear (in fact, it is incorrect as they have a typo, they should have gotten rid of *all* variables $x_{i+1}, .., x_n$). I would go from the third to fourth line in the following steps: 
\begin{align} 
&\sum_{x_1, ..., x_n} \sum_{i=1}^np(x_1, ..., x_n)\log[p(x_i|x_{i-1},...)]\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{x_1, ..., x_i}\sum_{x_{i+1}, ... ,x_n} p(x_1,...,x_n)\log[p(x_i|x_{i-1}, ...)]\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{x_1, ..., x_i}\log[p(x_i|x_{i-1},...)]\sum_{x_{i+1},...,x_n}p(x_1,...,x_n)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n\underbrace{\sum_{x_1,...,x_i}\log[p(x_i|x_{i-1},...)]p(x_1, ..., x_i)}_{-H(X_i|X_{i-1}, ...)}
\end{align} 
This uses the idea that we can sum out a subset of the variables: 
$$ \sum_{x_{i+1}, ..., x_n} p(x_1, ..., x_n) = p(x_1, ..., x_i) $$